# How to print values on single line

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have the following query on the command line, and I would like the output values to show up on single line so I can feed it to my monitoring system, I'm wondering how I can accomplish this via either perl , sed ,awk

My command line

```
activemq:query  -QQueue=PCA --view QueueSize,ConsumerCount,EnqueueCount,DequeueCount
```

output

```
ConsumerCount = 1
QueueSize = 0
DequeueCount = 148248
EnqueueCount = 148248
```

Desierd output

```
1 0 148248 148248
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe it to awk:

```
... | awk -F= '{printf "%s",$2}'
```

Output, as desired:

```
1 0 148248 148248
```

Comment: so much better then mine. +1 Another broken one: `... | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Why not posting this as an alternative?

Comment: nah, why post an inferior solution to the beauty of awk :-)

Answer (score 5):

Using command line switches is fun:

```
perl -anwe'print "$F[2] "'
```

`-a` autosplits the line on whitespace, and also thereby strips newline. We add a space and print the last field.

Answer (score 2):

Perl version:

```
... | perl -l40 -ane 'print $F[2]'
```

or (Perl 5.8.8)

```
... | perl -ne 'chomp; split /=/; print $_[1]'
```

---

Note: [Since Perl 5.12.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perldelta.html#split%28%29-and-%40_), "split() no longer modifies @_ when called in scalar or void context", so the second version will not work for Perl >= 5.12.0, but the first version should still works.

Testing:

```
$ cat t00.txt 
ConsumerCount = 1
QueueSize = 0
DequeueCount = 148248
EnqueueCount = 148248

$ cat t00.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; split /=/; print $_[1]'
 1 0 148248 148248

$ cat t00.txt | perl -l40 -ane 'print $F[2]'
1 0 148248 148248
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `@F` and not `@_`.

Comment: @TLP Yeah, just figure out how to use `-l` option.

Comment: Your code still does not work. You should run them before posting. In the first case, you need to use `$F[1]`, since the `@_` array is empty. In the second case, you need to use `$F[1]`, because the `@F` array only contains 2 items. I also recommend using `-w` even in one-liners, as it gives important warnings.

Comment: @TLP I did test them (please see the result in my updated answer), and they work.

Comment: @LeeDuhem +1 for split even though it is deprecated construct. `Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated`

Comment: And when I run the first one I get `Useless use of split in void context at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1, <> line 1.` etc.. The second one will work now, because you removed `-F=`. The first one *might* work if your Perl version allows implicit split to `@_`, but its been 10 years since I've heard of that happening, and it is also deprecated.

Comment: @TLP Oh, I am currently use the pretty old Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: If you want to skip the `-a` switch, you could do `(split /=/)[1]`. Very clever use of `-l40`. It took me a while to notice, but it actually works very well in this context.

Comment: @LeeDuhem That would explain it. My Perl version does not allow this implicit split to `@_`, and so your code does not work for me.

Comment: @TLP Since Perl 5.12.0, "`split()` no longer modifies `@_` when called in scalar or void context."

Comment: @mpapec Thank you for point that out. Does not use new Perl for quite a while, and need to update my Perl knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one. Keeping pushing values in an array, and print the entire array at the end. This gives you a new-line at the end.

However, if your file is very huge, this will not be ideal. In that case, go with [TLP's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992135/970195) crafty one-liner.

```
... | perl -lane 'push @a, $F[2] }{ print "@a"'
```